# How is this Top Banner scroll-effect achieved?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I was curious how the top banner of this site is being achieved with jquery.

Some things that are throwing me a bit:

1. It looks like they aren't hiding the overflow, as the entire scroll bar is present.
2. Scrolling down wait for the animation to be completed.
3. When scrolling up, it stops before the banner comes back down. You must scroll up again to toggle the banner.

https://space10.io

Thanks!

Comment: That's not the real scroll bar, though.  It looks nothing like the default scroll bars for my operating system.  Perhaps they faked it to perfectly match your scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

The code responsible for the top banner isn't using jQuery as far as I can make out (it's obfuscated, but it just looks like it's written in JavaScript without the use of jQuery).

The effect is achieved using the [mousewheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel) event.

If you scroll the page with the keyboard (space or page down).  The effect does not happen, and the experience is broken.